What's an event I can listen to, to make sure my styles have been loaded and applied?
I have a parent window from where I grab all stylesheet links from inside the head. I then cloneNode those styles, and finally, appendChild to the iframe's head.
When would be the event that I could listen to inside my iframe, that'll let me know that all those styles have been loaded and applied?
I control everything inside this application, so, anything goes. I've tried load and DOMContentLoaded, but the thing is - the iframe's already loaded. Am looking for a way to await appendChild and await loadStyle().

Instead of having the parent window's code append the cloned nodes to your iframe, have it call a global function on the iframe's window and pass them in so that function can do it. In that function, add load and error handlers before appending the elements. When all the load handlers have fired, the styles have been applied. (Or of course, if any of the error handlers fired, there's a problem. :-) )
Here's a rough draft. In the parent (be sure not to run this code until after the iframe has loaded):
const styles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("link[rel=stylesheet]"), (s) => s.cloneNode());
document.getElementById("f").contentWindow.addStyles(styles);

In the iframe:
function addStyles(styles) {
    const loadPromises = styles.map((style) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        style.addEventListener("load", resolve);
        style.addEventListener("error", reject);
        document.head.appendChild(style);
    }));
    Promise.all(loadPromises)
    .then(
        () => {
            // All loaded...
        },
        () => {
            // At least one failed...
        }
    );
}

Make sure that's in a non-module script, or alternatively add it to the window object by doing window.addStyles = addStyles;, so that it's accessible via the window object.
Again, that's just a rough sketch, though it worked on a Chromium browser when I tested it.

Alternatively, you could also use BroadcastChannel and just send the URLs of the stylesheets instead of actual link nodes.
Or you could have the parent window do all the work and call a global function in the iframe window when it's done.
Or you could have the parent window do all the work and then have it raise a custom event on the iframe window when it's done. (Slightly embarrassed this is the last thing I thought of; it's probably cleanest.)

That's really smart, yea. The load of the style element is the core of the issue here. I tweaked your answer, and got what I needed, thanks :)
